# What is the relation between Fowlers paterns for objects hierarchy to RDBMS mapping and Hibernate inheritance strategies?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, orm

I've read Fowler's patterns which allows to decide how to map objects hierarchy to the RDBMS and found 3 options.

let's say we have following hieararchy

```
absract class Parent{...}

class Child extends Parent{....}

class GrandChild extends Child {....}
```

1.[Class Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) - we will have 3 tables: fot `Parent` and `Child` and `GrandChild`
2.[Single Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) -  we will have single table with all fields in hierarchy (for Parent and Child and GrandChild at this case)
3. [Concrete Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) - we will have tables for only concrete classes - for Child and GrandChild at this case

But acccording the articles I've read(for example -https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance) there are 4 options:

1. `MappedSuperclass` – the parent classes, can't be entities
2. `Single Table` – the entities from different classes with a common ancestor are placed in a single table
3. `Joined Table` – each class has its table and querying a subclass entity requires joining the tables
4. `Table-Per-Class` – all the properties of a class, are in its table, so no join is required

Obviously Flowler's [Single Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) corresponds `Single Table` from Hibernate

Looks like Flowler's [Concrete Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) corresponds `Table-Per-Class` and `MappedSuperclass` from Hibernate

And now we have Flowler's [Class Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) from one side and `Joined Table` from another(Hibernate) side.

as you can see we have 2 hibernate options corresponding the only Flowler's [Concrete Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html). Could you explain difference between these strategies?